# Groupby and Modify Pandas Dataframe Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have been at it for few hours now, and unfortunately haven't been able to do it in an efficient way. I am sorry, it seems like elementary. I need to groupby a dataframe on two columns and change another subset of columns(from the same dataframe) depending on the value of yet another column in the same dataframe.

My dataframe looks like below:

```
state | binned_age   | mnth1 | mnth2 | key
 NSW  |  24-34       | 400   | 200   | 250
 VIC  |  65-150      | 150   | 200   | 450
 VIC  |  65-150      | 50    | 200   | 450
 VIC  |  65-150      | 600   | 200   | 450
 VIC  |  65-150      | 900   | 200   | 450
```

I'm trying to transform this dataframe like so:
1) group on `state` and `binned_age`
2) where `month1` and `mnth2` are greater than `key`, replace with `1`, elsewhere, replace with `0`

Final result should look like this:

```
 state | binned_age   | mnth1 | mnth2 | key
     NSW  |  24-34       | 1     | 0     | 250
     VIC  |  65-150      | 0     | 0     | 450
     VIC  |  65-150      | 0     | 0     | 450
     VIC  |  65-150      | 1     | 0     | 450
     VIC  |  65-150      | 1     | 0     | 450
```

I am at this stage, but not sure how I can transform it to above dataframe.

```
grouped_df = sample_cols.groupby(['state', 'binned_age'])
grouped_df.apply(lambda x: x.max_exp_1_mnth > x.max_exp_2_mnth)
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `groupby` is not necessary, because no comparing per groups. So compare filtered columns by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and convert `True/False`s to `1/0` by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
cols = ['mnth1','mnth2']
df[cols] = df[cols].gt(df.key,axis=0).astype(int)
print (df)
  state binned_age  mnth1  mnth2  key
0   NSW      24-34      1      0  250
1   VIC     65-150      0      0  450
2   VIC     65-150      0      0  450
3   VIC     65-150      1      0  450
4   VIC     65-150      1      0  450
```

If performance is important use numpy alternative with broadcasting:

```
df[cols] = (df[cols].values > df.key.values[:, None]).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you need groupby for this, you can do this as:

```
df[['mnth1','mnth2']]=np.where(df[['mnth1','mnth2']].gt(df.key,axis=0),1,0)
print(df)
```

---

```
   state     binned_age    mnth1  mnth2  key
0   NSW      24-34             1      0  250
1   VIC      65-150            0      0  450
2   VIC      65-150            0      0  450
3   VIC      65-150            1      0  450
4   VIC      65-150            1      0  450
```

Comment: thanks very much. I wasn't thinking clearly. Just for the sake of argument, if I need to do a similar task but with groupby, please can you suggest a way?

Comment: @Ahsan probably `df.groupby(['state','binned_age']).apply(lambda x: x[['mnth1','mnth2']].gt(x.key,axis=0).astype(int))`